# api call HTTP address format issue

Tags: python, api

I am trying to API call with python 3. Could you help with the following error please. ANy help is appreciated.

The code:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("https://api.cryptoapis.io")

headers = {
  'Content-Type': "application/json",
  'X-API-Key': "***********************"
}
conn.request("GET", "v1,bc,xrp,testnet,address,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 887, in _get_hostport
    port = int(host[i+1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '//api.cryptoapis.io'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jvcea_weekly.py", line 215, in <module>
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("https://api.cryptoapis.io")
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 851, in __init__
    (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 892, in _get_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
http.client.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//api.cryptoapis.io
```

'

Comment: posting your api key on public forum?

Comment: i think also test it out with postman, you are getting a response for the API or not, also update the API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTPConnection` doesn't accept a *URL*, it accepts a *host*. I.e. it wants to be called like this:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("api.cryptoapis.io")
```

Since you're not explicitly passing a port number, it's trying to extract the port number from the host string and expects a format like `host:port`. So it finds `//` as the port in your string after the `:`.

If you want to create an HTTPS connection, use `HTTPSConnection` instead of `HTTPConnection`.